# what is the event flow in jquery mobile with phonegap 2.1.0?

Tags: javascript, events, jquery-mobile, cordova, onload

I'm newbie to jquery mobile and Phonegap. Please correct me if im wrong anywhere.

I started an application which have five html pages -home.html, menu.html, orders.html, reservation.html, about.html.

I wrote a common JavaScript file script.js shared by all these html files which holds common JavaScript functions.And in homeactivity I'm adding menu.html because I need that page by default.

Now I need to run init() function which have different code in each five pages which should run after page is shown to user.

from the documentation of jquery mobile and Phonegap I got these are the event related to page load:

> mobileinit, pagebeforecreate, pagecreate, pageinit, pagebeforeshow, pageShow, onDeviceReady

so for my understanding I added this code in all five html files and in common JavaScript file before loading jquerymobile.js. so my each html file head look like this:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

     //reservation.html is replace by relative file name in each diff file
     function onDeviceReady() {
         // Empty
        console.log('ondeviceReady function on reservation.html');
     }

     $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
         //apply overrides here
         $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
     });

     $(document).bind('pagebeforecreate',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagebeforecreate triggered');
     });


     $(document).bind('pagecreate',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagecreate triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pageinit',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pageinit triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pagebeforeshow',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagebeforeshow triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pagebeforehide',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagebeforehide triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pageshow',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pageshow triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pagehide',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagehide triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pagebeforeload',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pagebeforeload triggered');
     });

     $(document).bind('pageload',function(){
         console.log('reservation.html pageload triggered');
     });
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/script.js"></script>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

when I started application the console.log is in this order:

```
   menu.html - pagebeforecreate
   script.js - pagebeforecreate
   menu.html - pagecreate
   script.js - pagecreate
   menu.html - pageinit
   script.js - pageinit
   menu.html - pagebeforeshow
   script.js - pagebeforeshow
   menu.html - pageShow
   script.js - pageShow
   menu.html - onDeviceReady
   script.js - onDeviceReady
```

This is as I expected. But, when I navigated to home.html (all five files linked in each file), something going wrong and console.log is as below:

```
   menu.html - pagebeforeload
   script.js - pagebeforeload
   menu.html - pagebeforecreate
   script.js - pagebeforecreate
   menu.html - pagecreate
   script.js - pagecreate
   menu.html - pageinit
   script.js - pageinit
   menu.html - pageload
   script.js - pageload
   menu.html - pagebeforehide
   script.js - pagebeforehide
   menu.html - pagebeforeshow
   script.js - pagebeforeshow
   menu.html - pagehide
   script.js - pagehide
   menu.html - pageShow
   script.js - pageShow
   menu.html - onDeviceReady
   script.js - onDeviceReady
```

even I removed page events from each page and added **pageShow** event in external javascript file and calling **init()** function and I defined **page specific init()** function in each html file **before adding external Javascript file in header** in each page. still everytime i navigate to different pages **only init() function from menu.html**  is getting executed, which is added in homeactivity.

so here no event in home.html is not getting triggered. I have page specific javascript should be run only after once page is shown. please help me out here where I'm doing wrong.